# PC Rebooting Without Cause

Tags: reboot, desktop-computer

For the last 2 years or so, my PC has been rebooting itself intermittently.  There is no discernable pattern to the reboots, only that they seem most likely when I'm just about to press the "save" button.

It seems to come in waves.  For instance, it was really bad about 8 months ago.  The PC would reboot every 15 minutes.  After a while it'd be good for six hours, then reboot again.  Then it'd be fine for another week or so and out of the blue, boom.  It started again Friday after many months of being fine, and has been problematic since then.  Though I did have a 30 hour stretch Sunday where it was fine.

One more thing I've noticed, intentionally rebooting the machine or shutting it down for a while seems to increase the frequency of the problem.  But overall it's rewally arbitrary.  It makes it really difficult to determine the cause when there is no pattern to it.  All I can do is swap out a part and wait for a reboot, and that'd prove that part wasn't the cause.

It's not a software problem as it happens in Windows and Linux.  It's not a heat issue as temperatures are normal, and heat isn't in excess.  It's happened when the PC is cool and hot, and everywhere inbetween.

I've also ruled out the PSU, GPU, ram, and HDD.  Each of these have been removed or swapped out and the problem has still ocurred.

Really all that's left is the motherboard and CPU, but I don't have any spare parts to swap in to test it.

Possibly related, my BIOS is frequently reset.  I have to go in and fix my clock, boot order, and other settings.  This makes me think it's a motherboard issue, but I know very little about motherboards.

Does anybody have any insight into what the cause of this might be?  I've been struggling with this issue for years, and it's causing problems with my work now and needs to be fixed.

[System Specifications here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01175536&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3550554)

[Motherboard specifications here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01077641&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=3550554)

Thank you.

Comment: how old is the system overall? The exact specifications would help as well.

Comment: @Breakthrough: It happens in both Linux and Windows.

Comment: I know you swapped out your RAM, but that's **not** a good way to ensure it's okay.  Download [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/), and ensure your RAM passes.  To check your CPU, you can use [Prime95](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=103) (just be careful, it causes very high CPU load, and thus high temperatures).

Comment: Do u use an UPS or a Voltage Stabilizer? If yes, try changing them; if no, try using them. Helped me personally.

Comment: Sounds like it's the motherboard, since that's really all that's left.  No more parts on hand?  Time to visit a repair shop.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek, the system is 3-4 years old now.  It was a prebuild originally from HP (m9080n) but I've updated the ram, HDDs, and GPU since then.  Motherboard and CPU are original.

Comment: @Breakthrough, I've run Memtest86+ for one pass before, but I can try running it for longer.  I'll also try running Prime95, though intensive tasks don't seem to have any correlation to the rebooting.  It honestly seems entirely random.  Maybe a motherboard short.

Comment: I do not, though I've shopped around for a UPS before.  I've had this happen at three different homes though so I don't think it's a voltage spike problem.  Sometimes it happens after an hour of use, sometimes after five seconds of another reboot.  Sometimes not for months...

Comment: Any chance your CPU is running hot? High temperatures may cause rebooting.

Comment: See if there's any bulging caps. Its too new for that, but wouldn't hurt to check

Comment: If you can, try a new power supply, no good way to test them.

Comment: @Dennis I've not noticed any abnormal temperatures from the CPU.  I don't think it's a heat problem as it can happen immediately after the PC has been shut off for a while.  In fact it seems more common when cold.

Comment: @Moab I have tried another PSU, it didn't stop the reboots.  I think we're down to mobo and CPU at this point.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote just for getting 30 hours of uptime on Sunday

Comment: @SquareWheel Prime95 can also reveal any problems with the CPU itself.  It verifies (in a similar way to Memtest86+) each result it gets to ensure that nothing was corrupted (which would indicate an unstable computer).  It will detect both CPU and memory errors.  My warning about heat was literally just that; wasn't assuming you had heat issues, just wanted to forewarn you that Prime95 will make your CPU hotter than any other possible thing you could run on your computer (okay, maybe except for LINPACK).

Comment: @Breakthrough, I'll give it a spin and see what happens.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

That you need to set the clock and boot order frequently means that the battery on the motherboard is bad. You could try to replace it.

Since you have ruled out other factors, perhaps the above manifests itself in reboots for some reason. Otherwise I'd suspect the PSU (*always* suspect the PSU :-) ). Or it is just a symptom of the motherboard being very old, which might have worn out other components as well. You say you have exchanged everything but the motherboard and CPU - it's probably one of those then. Probably the motherboard.

A distant last option is that your electricity is so spiky that the computer reboots, but you should notice this well more in lamps and other equipment. Computers are often less sensitive to this than other appliances since the PSU contains large capacitors to handle the power switching, and thus can handle short outages without problems.

Comment: I've already replaced the CMOS battery twice in the last year, that can't be it.  I've also tried using two different PSUs, so I don't think that's the problem.  As for voltage spikes, this has happened at three different homes if that indicates anything.  I think it must be the motherboard.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I suspect a heat issue.  I cannotthink of any other issue besides a power supply problem that would cause a systme reboot besides the cpu causing it.

Comment: I've monitored the temperatures pretty closely and they're well within reason.  It actually seems to happen more frequently when everything is cold, and begins rebooting less frequently after it gets going.